# How do I toggle 1 boolean in javascript every time the page loads, without localstorage or cookies?

Tags: javascript, api

I need to toggle a boolean every time the page loads. I can't use localStorage OR cookies.

I've tried using localStorage and cookies. problem is that i'm in a sandbox that doesn't allow that.

What I CAN do is do requests to webpages. Maybe one can toggle between returning true or false every time a website loads;
like:

First load:

HTTP GET returns true (or 1, it's just an example)

Second load:

HTTP GET returns false (or 0)

Third load:

HTTP GET returns true (or 1)

ETC.

Is there an existing API or something for that?

Comment: a webpage can't toggle ... what is your server side running?

Comment: Don't know what your backend looks like, but should be able to implement that in about 5-10 lines in whatever language. As long as it's global, and not per user session, but even then...

Comment: A code snippet of what you have tried please

Comment: @JaromandaX It can using javascript and some other stuff
@RobbyCornelissen I sadly can't access the backend
@CraigWayne ```if (document.cookie.includes('jarswitchtoggle=1')) {
var dotsw=true
document.cookie.replace('jarswitchtoggle=1' , 'jarswitchtoggle=0')
} else {
 var dotsw=false
 if (document.cookie.includes('jarswitchtoggle=0')) {
// document.cookie.replace('jarswitchtoggle=0' , 'jarswitchtoggle=1')
 //} else {
 //document.cookie=document.cookie+';jarswitchtoggle=1'
// }
  
}```

Comment: `It can using javascript and some other stuff` you're wrong - prove me wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hash, something like:

```
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
    if (window.location.hash == '#1') {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='0';
        window.location.hash = '0';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML ='1';
        window.location.hash = '1';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: UPDATE: There was an option to disable hash clearing! Thanks!